# Gatwick Airport bag-drop information (WizzAir, South Terminal)?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, lgw, fragile-luggage

I am looking for information on how to check my luggage at Gatwick Airport (flying with WizzAir). I can't find much and the airports official page (https://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/flying-out/check-in/) is not helping me.

So, I have done online check-in and I now have a printed flight-pass. I have one luggage to check in. Here are my questions:

1. How do I proceed on arrival at Gatwick Airport (South Terminal)? (3 hours before my flight)
2. Is the automatic bag-drop service free?
3. Do I have to look for my specific airline's bag-drop machines or are they all generic?
4. Where are the bag-drop machines roughly located (South Terminal, Gatwick Airport)?
5. Do they support "fragile luggage"?

Edit: I don't need "early bag-drop". Just "normal" (2,3 hours before flight).

Comment: “Fragile luggage” just doesn’t exist for airlines. All luggage will be treated the same, even if you wrap it in flashy orange with neon yellow “fragile” 10cm-high lettering. Either pack it appropriately or take it with you in the cabin (if it fits allowances of course).

Comment: thanks! I still remember checking in my luggage and then asked if they were fragile items in there, whereas they pointed me to the "fragile luggages" section. That was the norm 15 years ago AFAIR Today there is a charge for the airport to provide a proper FAQ. Perhaps next would be the customer to decide their risk-factor. Though I appreciate no-frills travel.